# Ribbon is disabled when I Filter an external list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, filter, bcs, external-list

I created an external list in sharepoint 2010 (SP1) using SPD. The backend is sql server.  The I added a wildcard filter on a column called Source_System (and a limit filter).

The out of the box view worked fine, meaning that I could edit and delete items from the ribbbon.

I then used SPD to add a Querystring paramter to the view called Source System and Configired the Finder in SPD  to Pass the QueryString  {SOURCE_SYSTEM} into the Filter.

The filter works fine , but when i pass in a  SOURCE_SYSTEM on the QueryString filter, the Ribbon Buttons to edit and delete are disabled. With no QueryString Filter they work fine, its only when I filter the list with a query string they are disabled.

Anyone know how to get around this?

BTW ...The View and edit commands in the ECB work fine, its just the ribbbon!

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Same issue on my side.